# Issue with IE only in CSS/design, crossbrowser compatibility

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

This question is based on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SKJvv/3/). It is a navigation design with two top level menu items and three submenus (structured for accessibility without script). An element to look at may be:

```
     <nav class="top-menu">
```

There is one pressing issue:

1. Just open the JSFiddle in Internet Explorer and see. Why does it drop down like that only in IE? Even in IE9 and 10.

Any help here will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a common problem with zooming by an amount that is not a power of 2. For instance, you'll notice that the alignment issue is fixed at 50% zoom. Personally I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: @Kolink In some cases the displacement is visible without zooming. At this point I'm fanatic about correcting it :)

Comment: When I look at it in IE9 it doesn't look bad. Unless if you are talking about the arrow

Comment: I'm with Kolink, IE isn't worth worrying about. It's a POS.

Comment: dmc, while that may entirely be true, that's a poor way of looking at a design problem.. People (albeit those who know no better) still use IE, so thus, it has to be taken into account. ... ... OR at the very least given an IE-only splash screen with a Chrome download option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have noticed that "top-header" blocks had different heights, and to fix this I've added line-height CSS rule:

```
.top-header {
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    + line-height: 28px; 
}
```

And it currently seems same for me in IE and Chrome.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SKJvv/6/)

Comment: Poking around in the browsers respective developer tools IE reports the computed height of `.top-header` in IE is 36.8px while in Chrome it is 29px.  Setting `line-height` as mishik suggests fixes the problem or you could set `height:29px` as well

Answer (score 6):

add

```
height :136px \0/;
```

at the end of .top-header 
and the problem will be solved check
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SKJvv/12/)

Answer (score 4):

You may use some 'tape' to fix this in IE. :)

Via CC, add a `border-bottom: white 10px solid;` or `outline:white 10px solid;`
http://jsfiddle.net/SKJvv/7/ http://jsfiddle.net/SKJvv/8/

It doesn't explain much what layout is playing about.

*(CC included : http://jsfiddle.net/SKJvv/10/ )*